# How to fix this Error "subscripted value" on C language?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

I got this Error from my program

```
error: subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector
   84 |   }while(deck[row][column] != 0);
      |                   ^
poker_comp.c:85:13: error: subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector
   85 |    deck[row][column] = card;
      |
```

Can help me to fix this error?

Here's the code

```
typedef struct card{
    int pips;
    char suit;
    bool flipped;
    struct card *next;
}Card;

typedef struct deck{
    int size;
    Card *top;
    //int topcardindex;
}Deck;

typedef struct player{
    char* name;
    Card *c1, *c2;
    int account;
}Player;


#include "poker.h"

/* [ Chapter 9: Structures and Unions ]  
 *
 *  Functions to create
 *  
 *  1) newcard(-,-): Use malloc
 *
 *  2) newdeck(): Use malloc 
 *  
 *  3) newplayer(): Use malloc
 *
 *      4) eject(): only can pop out from the top of the Deck 
 *          (pop from the bottom is not allowed) 
 *
 *  5) shuffle(-): use srand/rand
 */

/* function to complete */
Card* newcard(int _pips,char _suit){
    
    /* write codes */   
    Card *newCard = malloc(sizeof(Card));
    newCard->pips = _pips;
    newCard->suit = _suit;
    
    return newCard; 
}
    
Deck* newdeck(){
    
    /* write codes */
    Deck *deck = malloc(sizeof(Deck));
        
    Card* cursor;   
    for(char s = 0; s <= 3; s++) {
        for(int p = 2; p <= 14; p++) {
            if(deck->top == NULL) { 
                deck->top = newcard(p,s);
                cursor = deck->top;
            } else {
                cursor->next = newcard(p,s);
                cursor = cursor->next;
            } deck->size;
        }
    }
    return deck;
}

Player* newplayer(char* _name,int _account){
    
    /* write codes */   
    Player *player = malloc(sizeof(Player));
    player->name = _name;
    player->account = _account; 
    
    return player;
}

Card* eject(Deck* deck) {
    Card* temp;

    /* write codes */
    //for(i = 0; i<deck->size; i++)
    //  temp[i]=i;
    //deck_card = deck->size;
    
    temp = deck->top;
    deck->top=temp->next;

    return temp;
}

void shuffle(Deck* deck){
    
    /* write codes */
    
    int row, column, card;
    
    for(card=1; card<=52; card++){
        do{
            row = rand() %52;
            column = rand()%52;
        }while(deck[row][column] != 0);
            deck[row][column] = card;
    }
    
    srand(clock());     
    
    if(deck->size<=20) printf("\n\nERROR: deck size should be bigger than 20\n\n");
    unsigned char index = rand()%(deck->size-20)+10;
    unsigned char endex = rand()%(deck->size - index-1)+1;
    
    Card *cindex, *cendex, *aendex, *bendex;
    cendex = deck->top;
    for(int i = 0; i < index-1; i++) {
        cendex = cendex->next;
    }
    
    head->top = deck->top;
    head->size = index-1;
    cindex = cendex->next;
    cendex->next = NULL;
    aendex = cendex;
    cendex = cindex;
    
    for(int i = 0; i < endex-1; i++) {
        cendex = cendex->next;
    }

    
    mid->top = cindex;
    mid->size = endex-1;
    cindex = cendex->next;
    cendex->next = NULL;
    bendex = cendex;
    cendex = cindex;

    for(int i =0; i < (deck->size - index - endex-1); i++) {
        cendex = cendex->next;
    }
    cendex->next = NULL;
    
    
    tail->top = cindex;
    tail->size = (deck->size - index - endex);  
    
    deck->top = mid->top;
    aendex->next = tail->top;
    bendex->next = head->top;

    free(head); free(mid); free(tail);      
    return;
}

void freedeck(Deck* deck){      

    /* write codes */   

    return;
}
```

Comment: `deck[row][column]` Not sure why you think you can do that. `deck` is not a 2D array. In fact it is not an array at all. It points to just a single structure.

Comment: Welcome to SO. For most compilation errors reported by the compiler the[MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) can be really short. There is no need to include everything into the question. You could remove 80% of that code and still provide everything relevant. Just as a reminder: If people don't need to wade through loads of unrelated code they are more likely to help.

Answer (score 1):

When in doubt, check the data types.

- `deck` is of type `Deck *`, pointer to type `Deck` or `struct deck`.
- `deck[row]` gives you a variable of type `Deck` or `struct deck`. This is not a pointer type.
- Further trying to index into `deck[row]` is invalid syntax, as to apply array subscripting operator `[]`, the operand has to be "pointer to complete object type". In your case, this violates the rule, so this is invalid syntax.

If you have to use this syntax, `deck` has to be of type `Deck **`.